# Getting error in Java Code when trying to load the Firefox using selenium Web Driver

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am getting below error even though I had set the correct path for gecko driver.

Exception mention below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Selenium\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64.exe
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:141)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
at com.package1.Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Selenium\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64.exe
```

Which means the *GeckoDriver* binary doesn't exist as `C:\Selenium\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64.exe`

### Solution

While working with *Selenium 3.x* you need to download the *GeckoDriver* binary in zip/tar format from [this site](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), extract the binary and store it anywhere within your system. Then in your program within `System.setProperty()` line you need to mention the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* binary as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Comment: I had downloaded the GeckoDriver and placed the correct path as well but still it is not picking up the file.

Comment: I have gecko driver in C:\Selenium\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\geckodriver.exe. Below is my code: package com.package1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


public class Test {
 
 public static void main(String args[])  {
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  //driver.close();
  driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com");
  
 }

}

Comment: Issue resolved.There was some path issue which i was giving in my code. Thanks Debanjan